# how to append data frame to existed formulated excel file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

if u have a formulated excel file and now wants to append data frame by python then how..

I used this code but did not  get  output

`mypath="C:\\Users\\egoyrat\\Desktop\\smt tracker\\Swap Manual.xlsx" book = load_workbook(mypath) ws= book['Main'] for row_data in now_append:`enter code here `ws.append(row_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write to the file by cells, you can do it. Below is the code...
Assuming that, by formulated, you mean the cells have format (color, font, etc.) and you want to write data without changing the format of the cells)

```
import numpy as np
#Create random 10x3 dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx', read_only=False)
ws=wb['Sheet2']

#Write header
for col in range(df.shape[1]):
    ws.cell(1, col+1).value = df.columns[col]

#Write the data
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for column in range(df.shape[1]):
        ws.cell(row=row+2, column=column+1).value = df.iloc[row,column]
wb.save('output.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Output - Before writing

[image: Before writing]

After writing your data

[image: After writing]

**Option 2 - based on Charlie Clark's input**

This does the same thing as above, but a little faster/better....

```
import numpy as np
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx', read_only=False)
ws=wb['Sheet2']
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False)
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
        
wb.save('output.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: now how to append other data frame in to output.xlsx

Comment: @RatiGoyal - Please read the code. A new dataframe ````df```` has been added to the excel file. Before screenshot was empty, After screenshot has the data!

Comment: Using the `dataframe_to_rows()` utility is probably the best option.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark. I've added the dataframe_to_rows code as well. I was hoping it would be possible to just say ````for row in dataframe_to_rows(.....)   ws.append(row)````. But doesn't work(runs but no update in excel). That would have been faster still. Does this work only on new excel files?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Might need to check where the worksheet row counter is.